# transpose Keyword not working as I expected

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have this code where it supposed to reverse a list (decided to do it in complex way instead)
and I was trying to print the transpose version of the reversed list but it seem to not work out

```
import numpy as np
  
    def func(n):
        dictionary = {
            0: 1 + 1,
            1: 0
        }
        l = []
        l.extend([n,n+1,dictionary[0] + 1])
        if(l == [1,2,3]):
            f = np.transpose(l)
            return f[::-1]
    
    func(1)
```

The output:

```
array([3,2,1])
```

What I was expecting for the output to be:

```
[3]
[2]
[1]
```

Comment: The result you're expecting isn't a single value. The reason that "transposing" a 1-dimensional input doesn't do anything, is because the point of transposition is to swap axes, and there isn't another axis to swap with. That said: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. We don't need to see the busy-work that creates the `l` value. All the code you need for this question is `print(np.transpose(np.array([1,2,3])))`. And the way you answer it is to read the documentation.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel , Oh wow that so obvious silly me. Thanks!